# Qt 5.7 QDockWidget default size

Tags: qt, qt5, qt-designer, qt5.7

I am trying to have following setup:

at start (when main window is opened) I want to have 2 QDockWidgets at left with width 400px and height 1/2 (each) of QMainWindows height. At the left, 3 QDockWidgets with width 400px and height 1/3 (each) of QMainWindows height. All of 5 widgets **have to be resizable**. That means using `setFixSize()` won't work in this case.

So far I've tried changing `Geometry>Width` and `Gemetry>Height` in designed -> didn't work.

Then I tried using `resize()` in main window constructor but it didn't work either.

Why doesn't `Gemetry>Height/Width` and `resize()` have any influence on widgets size and how to achieve main window layout as described above?

Answer (score 2):

The dock-widgets will be added to the layout of the main-window, so resizing them will have no effect. One work-around for this is to reimplement the `sizeHint` of the content widget that is added to each dock-widget.

I suppose another way of looking at this is to let the user arrange the dock-widgets in whatever way they prefer, and then use [saveState](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#saveState) and [restoreState](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#restoreState) to manage the initial state.

Comment: And if content of a docking widget is, e.g., `QWebEngineView`? I don't think inheriting from it only to reimplement `sizeHint` is a good idea, or is it not?

Comment: @carobnodrvo. Just use a simple `QWidget` subclass as a container for your real content.

Comment: But my real content is `QWebEngineView`.

Comment: @carobnodrvo. So what? Just add a layout to the container widget and then add whatever widget(s) you like to that layout. You might also want to set the layout margins to zero,